# Can't get PHP code to work

Tags: php, mysql, short-url

I have this code, mainly it is meant to create shorurls for my site. But I simply cannot get it to work. Do you see something wrong with it? Is it ok to run a while() inside another one?

```
$urloriginal = $nt['fecha']."/".$nt['titulolower'];
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$shortcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shorturls WHERE urloriginal = '".$urloriginal."' LIMIT 1");
while($urlitem = mysql_fetch_array($shortcheck)) {
    if($urlitem['urloriginal'] !=  "0") {
        echo "http://neutronico.com/u/".$urlitem['id'];
    } else {
        mysql_close($shortcheck);
        mysql_query("INSERT into shorturls (urloriginal) VALUES ('$urloriginal')") 
           or die(mysql_error());
        $shortget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shorturls WHERE urloriginal = '".$urloriginal."' LIMIT 1");
        while($urlitem2 = mysql_fetch_array($shortget)) {
            echo "http://neutronico.com/u/".$urlitem['id'];
        };
        mysql_close($shortget);
    };
};
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the expected output? What's the actual output?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `mysql-fetch-assoc`? - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Seems like you need to do some simple debugging

Comment: Close your connection at the end, seems your closing it for certain scenarios and leaving it open for others.

Comment: Since you are retrieving one result (you do LIMIT 1) I don't understand the need of a while loop.

Comment: We can't see where the components that build `$urloriginal` are set, but please be sure you have called `mysql_real_escape_string()` on them if they originate from user input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you're calling `mysql_close()` mid-script on a result set. Remove the call:

```
mysql_close($shortcheck);
```

`mysql_close()` is intended to be called on a resource link -- the database connection.  Not on a query result resource.  It is called implicitly when the script exits, so you needn't call it at all unless you have specific memory requirements.  I think you are intending to call [`mysql_free_result()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-free-result.php), but again this is called implicitly and you needn't call it unless you need to manage memory.

Later, remove this call, as it is not closing a MySQL resource link.

```
mysql_close($shortget);
```

Comment: you're right, after he solves this, he will experience the problem I've described though, and the suspect of SQL injection that you spotted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's OK to nest while statements.

The main problem that I didn't spot at first is that you're closing your connection in the middle of the query, thus remove all `mysql_close` statements.

However, after you solve this, you'll face another problem, since you're using only one MySQL connection, the second query loses all results of the first query, so probably you stop at the first row, or the first time the `else` branch gets executed.

To make it work, you' can choose one of the two options:

- use two MySQL connections, and specify which one to use with the `$link_identifier` parameter `mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier ] )`
- run the first query, save all results in an array and then run the other queries, so the queries don't overlap. Use this option only if your table isn't too big.

Michael also suggested to check that your `$urloriginal` has been sanitized with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or you face a risk of SQL injection.